# How to update aggregations to collections

Tags: facebook, collections, facebook-opengraph

I have my current Facebook app and want to enable the new collections for the new news feed. How should I go about to do this?

I realized that when I create a new app - I have access to creating collections. Do I need to create a new app and delete my old app? I think that there should be a better migration technique to enable collections, right?

Comment: My understanding is that Collections would be in addition to Aggregations. But I still don't see a Collections tab in the Open Graph section of my app's settings, as outlined in <a href="https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/03/13/making-apps-a-bigger-part-of-timeline/">this blog post</a>. Maybe it's still rolling out?

Comment: Awesome - thanks for the confirmation! I think it is still rolling out too.. Just went in to create a new Fb app today and collections is missing :D

Comment: I too was looking for "Collections" under Open Graph for my app (as referenced in the docs) and came up empty-handed. I wish they'd have made sure the things the docs say exist actually did when you followed them!

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the Collections options are now live:
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/08/create-rich-user-stories-with-new-open-graph-tools/